# New and old monitor black outs

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, display

About a year ago, my monitor (LG E2242), which had been fine for years, started randomly  blacking out for a few seconds at a time, at a frequency that might sometimes be a few times a day, and sometimes a few times a minute. This was coupled with green/pink/black lines appearing sometimes.

During the course of a few months, I changed, in chronological order:

- my DVI cable,
- my HDD to an SSD (including reinstalling Windows),
- having other problems with my GPU (AMD Radeon HD 6950), I decided to change it to a new one (NVIDIA GTX 1060 3GB),
- my motherboard (ASROCK N68C-GS FX to ASROCK 970 Pro3 R2.0).

None of that seemed to fix it though, and I read that the green/pink/black lines were a sign of broken monitor, so I decided to buy a new one (BenQ GL2450). However, after a few weeks, the new monitor started blacking out
at random intervals too. Note that this one doesn't have the green/pink/black lines, which leads me to believe it might not be the same problem, or only a part of it.

About a month ago, I bought a new computer (ACER Aspire GX-781), with only new parts, that I didn't even build myself. I also changed the DVI cable to a new VGA/HDMI. But sure enough that didn't stop the blacking out.

There are two things I noticed that I'm not sure matter but I suppose they might. First, if I don't manually update the drivers through the device manager, the new monitor is referred to as "Generic PnP Monitor", no matter how much I uninstall the drivers and reboot. Second, it almost always blacks out when I displace it.

I have tried many options to fix it that I read here and there but none seemed to change anything, even if only to decrease the blackouts' rate.

The new monitor is still under warranty so I'm not too worried about it being broken, but I would still like to new if it really is or if the problem comes from something else (corrupted drivers per example).

About fluctuations in the electricity, I should mention that I actually moved while I had the first monitor, so I think it unlikely that I would have those in two different houses, especially since I live with 5 people who have no problems.
The power outlet is of type E (standard European).
I should also mention that both monitor's power indicator stay on during blackouts, only the screen itself "shuts down". Both monitors have a way to show that they are on but receive no signal, so I know that either it doesn't actually stop detecting, or for too short a window to change the power indicator.

Another fact that might be interesting is that though both monitors show manual changes in video display controller (i.e. between VGA and DVI), only the old monitor actually displays the pop up after blackouts as if there was actually a change in the connection or if it reset.

Additionally, I have a few questions. Is there such a thing as a spreading hardware corruption? Could it not have been fixed at first because I changed the parts one by one, not all at once? What could cause this kind of blackout in the first place? And most importantly, is my new computer at risk, being plugged to a "broken" monitor?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which video card are using now?  1. Nvidia 2. built-in to the new computer.  3. Other

Comment: @cybernard It's a built-in NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1060 3GB.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule hardware corruptions don't spread.

Your case seems to be very unusual.

Exception, if you had a cable with a short it in, the short could damage another unit.  This situation is extremely rare, and have not seen an actual case of this happening.

It blacks out when you displace it almost sounds like a bad/loose power cable, did you change that when you got the new monitor?

Another possibility, is you could have fluctuations in your electricity that are sufficient to be noticed by your monitor and not the computer.  The computer generally has larger capacitors in the power supply to ride out these fluctuations.  Presuming you have an outlet strip, what kind of shape is that in?

You could try a UPS or Un-interruptable Power Source ( basically a battery) which would eliminate these.  However, this is an educated guess.

Comment: Your first comment is a relief because it suggests that this problem shouldn't be linked to my new computer, only both my monitors and possibly my old computer.

I'm not sure which power cable you're referring to, but if it is the monitor's, I did change it entirely, as the monitors are distinct models from distinct brands.

I edited the post to add some details that relate to your suggestions. Those details make me hesitate about buying an UPS, do you still think I should try that?

Comment: I recently had a problem where sometime when I turned the monitor I got no signal and I had to unplug and replug the video cable to get it to register.  I bought a new monitor, no problems ever since.  I manage over 200 computers and have replaced them all several times, and I have yet to see a hardware corruption move from computer A to B.  I have seen a virus spread via the network.  When there is a monitor issue I swap the monitor with the computer next to it, and then swap it back for testing.  Never has computer B gotten computer A problem once swapped back to the original configuration.

Answer (score 0):

My new Philips does the same, since I bought it.

I am confident it is its the power supply, which guards against overvoltage, because the monitor blacks out, when my fridge starts or stops, the it takes 5 seconds to pick the input signal for UHD, which is normal after powering on.